# How to write pytest by external dataset in palantir foundry

Tags: pyspark, pytest, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I am able to write pytest functions by manually giving schema and input values. Using that schema and values I am creating dataframe and passes to code to check all transformations field values in foundry code repository. In place of manually passing schema and values. I want to store all the required data in the dataset outside that repository and use that dataset for pytest function to fetch all the required values and passing over to code to check all the transformed values.

May i know is there anyway to create input dataset outside the foundry code repository and use it as input for pytest function which is inside repository.

Comment: hi @monica-bp and welcome to stack overflow! I would recommend reading this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68305291/how-to-write-or-create-external-dataset-from-code-repository-within-foundry/68312195#68312195 

If it doesn't answer your question, could you please edit it so it becomes clearer of what you want to achieve and what you already tried?